# EditText focus issues

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have 2 problems with focus:

1. if my `EditText` is focussed and keyboard is shown; and I press the hardware back button, the keyboard
   hides but my `EditText` is still focussed (it still shows a blinking cursor).
2. when I press the actionbartoggle left of the `EditText` in my toolbar, while the keyboard is visible and the `EditText` is focussed, the keyboard hides and the `EditText` loses focus. This is correct.But when I press a `Button` (right of my `EditText`) while the keyboard is shown and the `EditText` has focus, nothing happens except the `Button` listener.
   When I put the attributes `focusableintouchmode=true` and `focusable=true` on the `Button`, the keyboard hides and the `EditText` loses focus but the listener doesn't work anymore

   ```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       style="@style/toolbarStyle"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarHeight" >

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/focusHolder"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:focusable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           >

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/refreshBtn"
               android:src="@drawable/refreshicon"
               android:layout_width="48dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:background="@null" />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/addressBar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/refreshBtn"
               android:singleLine="true"
               android:imeOptions="actionGo"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/searchicon"
               android:drawablePadding="5dp"
               style="@style/addressBarStyle"/>

       </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```

Comment: As you say you have two problems but 1st one is not a problem it is functioning correctly by pressing back you are just hiding the keyboard it does not make the `EditText ` lose the focus.

Comment: Ok how can i make it lose focus then? in the stock android apps this doesn't happen

Comment: write keypress event for back button and write your logic der

Comment: thanks alot it's working, any ideas for the second issue?

Comment: i am sorry but i am not able to understand it in the first place what you want

Comment: appearantly the keypress event is not working i was wrong, i did something like:
 addressBar.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {

   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
   {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
      {
        addressBar.clearFocus();
        focusHolder.requestFocus();
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
         
        });

Comment: onBackPressed doesn't work either when the keyboard is open btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
//hide a keyboard
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

//remove edittext focus
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: @PrisonMike you got any solution for this ?

Comment: No sorry this was 2 years ago